# How do I convert current time to GMT?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to get the value of `00:00:00 AM GMT`(12am) for the current day and then convert it to unix time. How would/should I go about doing that in javascript? Is there an outside data source that is more reliable then server time? I will be doing this in node on the server.

Thanks!

EDIT: This is what I did. Do you see any problems with this? Thanks again!

```
date = new Date()
start_date = Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(),date.getUTCMonth(),date.getUTCDate()) / 1000
```

Comment: That time is confusing, do you mean midnight (12AM) or midday (12PM)?

Comment: @SpacedMonkey 12AM, so the time of the beginning of the current day in GMT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is right, but you have got a nasty bug in there, you are mixing local year with UTC date and month, for a few hours around new year, depending on time zone, the local and the UTC year is different, so if you use the wrong year your result will be a whole year off.

There are two interpretations of your question. Either you want a result based on the local time, so the result at any given time will depend on the time zone. Or you want a result based on UTC time that is the same no matter time zone, but sometimes for some users the result will not be the local date.

Local time:

```
date = new Date()
start_date = Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate()) / 1000
```

UTC:

```
date = new Date()
start_date = Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(),date.getUTCMonth(),date.getUTCDate()) / 1000
```

Comment: Ah! Yes I didn't know `getUTCFullYear()` existed. That's is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These links have some good answers. I love epochconverter.com it's saved me many hours of frustration. The essence of the answer is to use the Javascript Date object to handle all the nastiness of converting dates around. This is generally what you should do in any languages. If you are doing date manipulation by hand *you will get it wrong*.

http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/#javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: w3schools can be wrong - http://w3fools.com/.  Instead look at MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @SpacedMonkey Any place can be wrong, but I agree MDN is a better ref. Updated post.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to start:

```
var now = new Date();
var then = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
var epoch = then.getTime();
```

Not sure what you want to do about DST, so you'll need to look at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Edit: To allow for different timezones:

```
var off = now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; /* tz is in mins so multiply to ms */
var midnight = new Date(then.getTime() - off);
var epoch = midnight.getTime();
```

Comment: this is a good start but will result in a unix stamp for the beginning of a day in my time zone.

Comment: there is a method called `Date.UTC(yyyy,mm,dd)` but I first need to know the current date in UTC.

Comment: check my edit, I added the solution I'm going with, until I find a gotcha.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I ended up doing for anyone else looking at this question.

```
date = new Date()
start_date = Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(),date.getUTCMonth(),date.getUTCDate()) / 1000
```

Please let me know if you see any reason this wouldn't work.

Comment: See my answer, it is still wrong to mix UTC and non-UTC methods, it will be a year off for a few hours around new year.